# Sticky header onscroll + window-size

Tags: html, css, header, sticky-footer

Hi I followed a code review snippet to implement in my website I'm steadily building on.

I've found out how to make it stick at the bottom and on a scroll down it sticks to the top. 
But when it shows at the bottom it doesn't show the nav completely.
HTML CODE:

```
<div class="header">
<nav id="main-navigation">
<ul>
  <li><a href="/archive">Archive</a></li>
  <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
<ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

JQUERY SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('#main-navigation');
$window.scroll(function(){
if ($window.scrollTop() >= 300) {
   nav.addClass('fixed-header');
}
else {
   nav.removeClass('fixed-header');
}
});</script>
```

CSS SNIPPET:

```
header{position:fixed;bottom:0;z-index:999999;}
.fixed{
position: absolute;
bottom:0; left:0;
width: 100%;
z-index:900; }
.fixed-header {
position: fixed;
top:0px; left:0;
width: 100%; 
}

nav {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background: #292f36;
postion:fixed;
z-index:100;
bottom:0px;
}

nav ul { 
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left:0;
text-align:right;
width: 960px; 
}
nav ul li { 
display: inline-block; 
line-height: 60px;
margin-left: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
text-decoration: none; 
color: #a9abae;
}
```

EXAMPLE TESTSITE:

[example](http://theoctopushideaway.nz/StackQA/#firstPage)

maybe I have to open a new stackexchange QA for this but does somebody see why my window-width is larger then my section-width? I checked and everything is width:100%? But again maybe I have to open a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see on your test site. You are stating 100% width for .fixed-header which is fine because is a fixed element it is ignoring the width of parent nodes and sizing to 100% of the screen.

However when you move to absolute, the 100% looks up the DOM tree to find an object with an explicit size. As you do not state one in any parent node then it is just auto sizing the the 960 of the content of the Nav ul.

```
header{
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   z-index:999999;
   min-width:100%; //width or min-width would work here
 }
```

This should give it an explicit width value when you remove the "fixed" status of the nav element because it will fall back to a 100% width fixed parent instead.